# Sign with Fourier transformation, convolution, periodicity

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

Let $x(t)$ be the sign with Fourier transformation
$$X(\omega)=\delta(\omega)+ \delta(\omega-\pi)+\delta(\omega-5)$$

and let $h(t)=u(t)-u(t-2)$.

1. Is $x(t)$ periodic?
2. Is the convolution of  $x(t)$ with $ h(t)$ a periodic sign?
3. Can  convolution of two non-periodic signs be a periodic sign?

$x(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int X(\omega) e^{j \omega t} d\omega$

How can I see if it is periodic?

Comment: What is the "sign with Fourier Transformation"? Do you mean "function" instead of "sign"?

Comment: $x(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int X(\omega) e^{j \omega t} d\omega$ @robjohn

Comment: So you've written that $x$ is the inverse Fourier Transform of $X$ (thus, $X$ is the Fourier Transform of $x$). Is $\delta(x)$ the Dirac delta distribution?

Comment: Yes, it is @robjohn, you are right :)))

Answer (score 1):

1. Since $\frac\pi5\not\in\mathbb{Q}$,
   $$
   x(t)=\frac1{2\pi}\left(1+e^{i\pi t}+e^{i5t}\right)
   $$
   is not periodic.
2. Since $h(t)=u(t)\ast(\delta(t)-\delta(t-2))$
   $$
   \begin{align}
   h(x)\ast x(t)
   &=\frac1{2\pi}\left(1-1+e^{i\pi t}-e^{i\pi(t-2)}+e^{i5t}-e^{i5(t-2)}\right)\ast u(t)\\
   &=\frac1{2\pi}\left(1-e^{-10i}\right)e^{i5t}\ast u(t)
   \end{align}
   $$
   which has period $\frac{2\pi}5$